# HTML Tooltip On Mouse Over SVG Path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

This is a fragment of a map and I need an HTML tooltip when I make an `OnMouseOver` in the PATH or in the link.
The purpose is to upload data later. Right now, the `OnMouse` options are for opacity change.

Any Suggestions? Thank you

```
    <svg id="svgCapa83346623" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <a id="12345" href="url.html" role="button" class="enllasos" target="_blank" title="title for my text"><path id="12345" d="m 146.95108,131.63456 -1.17877,0 -0.4715,-1.88594 -0.70725,0 0,-0.4715 -4.71505,1.88595 -1.65025,0.23575 -2.82903,0.70722 -0.23575,-1.41446 0.4715,-1.6502 -0.70725,-0.94296 -1.17877,-0.70724 0.94301,-0.94296 0.94301,-1.88595 0.47151,-0.70723 0,-0.47148 1.88602,0 2.59326,-1.17872 -0.70726,-0.70723 0,-1.41446 0.47151,-1.1787 2.59327,-1.41446 0.94301,-0.94298 1.65026,-0.23574 0.47151,0.94297 2.12177,0.94297 0.23575,0 0.23575,2.82892 -0.94301,0.94297 -0.23575,0.70723 0.70726,0.23574 1.65026,1.17871 0.70726,1.17872 0,0.70723 -0.47151,0.23574 0,0.47149 -0.23575,0.94296 -0.70726,0.94298 -0.70725,0 -0.23575,0.47148 -0.47151,0 0,0.70724 -0.23575,0.94296 -0.4715,0.94298" class="inactius" onClick="evt.target.setAttribute('class', 'marinomarca');" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1');"><title>title for my text</title></path></a>
    </svg>
```

Comment: You could create your own function and call it on hover. onmouseover="yourFuntion()"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery function to do that.
Here is an example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#svgCapa83346623').onmouseenter(function(){
    // do somthing
    })
}
```

Comment: The ID is a number that I retrieve from a query, could I substitute this for a class? For example, 

    $ (function () {
     $ ( '. Panoj'). OnmouseOver (function () {
      Alert ( "You wrote:");
     })
}
   </ Script>

Comment: Yes, you can use Class selector instead if ID